# Out of memory error when writing out spark dataframes to parquet format

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to query data from a database, do some transformations on it and save the new data in parquet format on hdfs.

Since the database query returns a large number of rows, I'm getting the data in batches and running the above process on every incoming batch.

**UPDATE 2:** The batch processing logic is:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}

class Batch(rows: List[String], 
            sqlContext: SQLContext) {

      // The actual schema has around 60 fields
      val schema = Array("name", "age", "address").map(field =>
                       StructField(field, StringType, true)
                   )

      val transformedRows = rows.map(rows => {

              // transformation logic (returns Array[Array[String]] type)

          }).map(row => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq))

      val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(transformedRows.asJava, schema)

}

val sparkConf = new sparkConf().setAppName("Spark App")
val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)

// Code to query database
// queryResponse is essentially an iterator that fetches the next batch on calling queryResponse.next

var batch_num = 0

while (queryResponse.hasNext) {
    val batch = queryResponse.next

    val batchToSave = new Batch(
                          batch.toList.map(_.getDocument.toString),
                          sqlContext)

    batchToSave.dataframe.write.parquet(batch_num + "_Parquet")

    batch_num += 1

}
```

My Spark version in 1.6.1 and the spark-submit is:

```
spark-submit target/scala-2.10/Spark\ Application-assembly-1.0.jar
```

The problem is that after a certain number of batches, I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error.

The entire stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
    at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:125)
    at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)
    at app.Application$.main(App.scala:156)
    at app.Application.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried coalescing the data into a single partition but that didn't make any difference.

```
dataframe.coalesce(1).write.parquet(batch_num + "_Parquet")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

Not doing a coalesce transform on the RDD still gives an error but the stacktrace is as follows. Seems to be an issue with Parquet.

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1855)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)
    at app.Application$.main(App.scala:156)
    at app.Application.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.IntList.initSlab(IntList.java:90)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.IntList.<init>(IntList.java:86)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.DictionaryValuesWriter.<init>(DictionaryValuesWriter.java:93)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.DictionaryValuesWriter$PlainBinaryDictionaryValuesWriter.<init>(DictionaryValuesWriter.java:229)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.dictionaryWriter(ParquetProperties.java:131)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.dictWriterWithFallBack(ParquetProperties.java:178)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.getValuesWriter(ParquetProperties.java:203)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.<init>(ColumnWriterV1.java:83)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.newMemColumn(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:68)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.getColumnWriter(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:56)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$MessageColumnIORecordConsumer.<init>(MessageColumnIO.java:183)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordWriter(MessageColumnIO.java:375)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.initStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:109)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.<init>(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:99)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.<init>(ParquetRecordWriter.java:100)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:303)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: no no no no no and no, do not coalesce - that is the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Comment: If your data (across all partitions, since you are coalescing the data ) is bigger than the available memory you will have OOM. More often than not, coalescing to a single partition is a bad practice, since it takes most of the scalability benefits from you.

Comment: Tried writing to parquet format without first coalescing. Still not working but the new stacktrace points to an issue with parquet

Comment: Okay, we need to see some codes, first the line you are saving your parquet (and any case class def if you are using them as your header), your spark submit and version would also be helpful.

Comment: wait, where is the path you are saving you parquet to? you just wrote the file names - don't do that either, just put down a file path i.e. `file:///home/subroot`

Comment: Updated the question with code/version/spark-submit. I'm using azure HDInsight so the path is handled by the default config. Files are saved to the Azure blob storage and can be listed by ``hadoop fs -ls``. The batches which are written before the app crashes can be accessed just fine.

Comment: How many executors, memory/executor, size of the file ?

Comment: I was working with 2 executors. The problem was fixed by increasing the memory allocated to both the driver and the executors to 20gb by passing `--executor-memory 20g --driver-memory 20g`

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem today as well. Turned out my execution plan was rather complex and [toString](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution.scala#L225) generated 150 MB of information which combined with String interpolation of Scala lead to the driver running out of memory.

You can try to increase the driver memory (I had to double it from 8 GB to 16 GB).